# Enabling testing repo on manjaro pacman.conf

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman

I thought I would be able to simply add

```
[testing]
serverName = testing

[community-testing]
serverName = community-testing
```

below community and core but it can't see the server.

Reading the wiki suggests it may need the path specified e.g. .../testing/os

But I have been unable to successfully do this.

Basically I want to be able to install testing packages via terminal without the risk of updating my system to broken versions e.g.
pacman -S package testing

Answer (score 2):

In Manjaro this seems to work slightly different. If you have a look at a [repo structure](https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/repo.manjaro.org/repos/) you can see that this is something like

```
+ stable
| + community
| + core
| + extra
| + multilib
+ testing
| + community
| + core
| + extra
| + multilib
```

And if you check `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` you will notice the url looks like

```
https://mirror.23media.com/manjaro/stable/$repo/$arch
```

It only takes `$repo` and `$arch` as parameter. Thus to switch to testing follow the guidelines at [Switching Branches](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Switching_Branches)